# Add the "current" id to two differents items in two differents menu in joomla 1.7

Tags: joomla, menuitem, joomla1.7, joomla-template

I have an article (with the id=6) on joomla 1.7

I have the main menu. In that menu, I created the item that show me only one article, the article with the id=6.

I have a secondary menu, that have 3 differents items. One of them, I have to link it to the same article with the id=6.

The problem is, that I need to add the "current" id to the item at the main menu, and in the item of the secondary menu, because both are links to the same article, so I have to highlight them.

By default, the system add me the current id to one item only when I click on that item, and doesn't when I show the same article that the item links.

Any help? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you change the second menu item to the type of 'Alias' and select the original menu item in the right hand side options?

Now instead of having two menu items with different internal menu ItemIds you have two items with the same ItemId. As long as your css is correct they *should* both be highlighted (or should that be highlit?).